# Duplicating and mirroring contents in TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have the following diagram, made in TikZ:

[image]

This is the code for it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    prod/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, fill=black!5, black!20},
    ct/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=5pt, ultra thick, minimum width=10mm, fill=black!5, black!20},
    ft/.style={circle, draw, minimum width=8mm, inner sep=1pt, fill=black!5, black!20},
    filter/.style={circle, draw, minimum width=7mm, inner sep=1pt, fill=black!5, black!20},
    mylabel/.style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily},
    >=LaTeX
    ]

\node[ct, label={[mylabel, black!20]Memory cell}, fill=black!5] (ct) {};
\node[filter, right=of ct, fill=black!5] (int1) {$f_g$};
\node[prod, right=of int1, fill=black!5] (x1) {$\times$}; 
\node[right=of x1] (ht) {$h_t$};
\node[prod, left=of ct, fill=black!5] (x2) {$\times$}; 
\node[filter, left=of x2, fill=black!5] (int2) {$f_h$};
\node[prod, below=5mm of ct, fill=black!5] (x3) {$\times$}; 
\node[ft, below=5mm of x3, label={[mylabel, black!20]right:Forget gate}, fill=black!5] (ft) {$f_t$};
\node[ft, above=of x2, label={[mylabel, black!20]left:Input gate}, fill=black!5] (it) {$f_t$};
\node[ft, above=of x1, label={[mylabel, black!20]left:Output gate}, fill=black!5] (ot) {$f_t$};

\foreach \i/\j in {int2/x2, x2/ct, ct/int1, int1/x1, x1/ht, it/x2, ct/it, ct/ot, ot/x1, ft/x3}
    \draw[->, black!20] (\i)--(\j);

\draw[->, black!20] (ct) to[bend right=45] (ft);

\draw[->, black!20] (ct) to[bend right=30] (x3);
\draw[->, black!20] (x3) to[bend right=30] (ct);

\node[fit=(int2) (it) (ot) (ft), draw, inner sep=0pt] (fit) {};

\draw[<-] (fit.west|-int2) coordinate (aux)--++(180:7mm) node[left]{$x_t$};
\draw[<-, black!20] ([yshift=1mm]aux)--++(135:7mm);
\draw[<-, black!20] ([yshift=-1mm]aux)--++(-135:7mm);

\draw[<-] (fit.north-|it) coordinate (aux)--++(90:7mm) node[above]{$x_t$};
\draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=1mm]aux)--++(45:7mm);
\draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=-1mm]aux)--++(135:7mm);

\draw[<-] (fit.north-|ot) coordinate (aux)--++(90:7mm) node[above]{$x_t$};
\draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=1mm]aux)--++(45:7mm);
\draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=-1mm]aux)--++(135:7mm);

\draw[<-] (fit.south-|ft) coordinate (aux)--++(-90:7mm) node[below]{$x_t$};
\draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=1mm]aux)--++(-45:7mm);
\draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=-1mm]aux)--++(-135:7mm);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Now I am trying to "mirror" Everything as the Picture below shows. Is this possible? (don't mind the mirrored letters, I don't want those to be mirrored, just the structure of the circles and Arrows inside the box).

[image]

To begin with, I am having trouble even with creating a second diagram that shows up under the first one. I tried using an outer for-loop, but it did not work at all.

Edit: As Symbol 1 provided an excellent answer below, which is to use \Spy to create a copy of the scope, I would like to refine my question and add that I would prefer to be able to draw Arrows between the two blocks (as seen with red in my hand drawn picture). I tried finding information about how to to this when having a copy made by Spy but could not find anything. Maybe it is not possible?

Comment: Have you tried `yscale=-1`?

Comment: @gernot I am sorry for not making it clear that I did not even manage to create the second box under the first one. I edited the question and mentioned that aswell. Your tip sounds promising though, but I need to understand how to create the second box first.

Comment: When you copy everything and but it between `\begin{scope}[yshift=-10cm] ...\end{scope}` you have a copy below it. Basically it is possible to mirror certain graphs, but only if you are careful how you position nodes. tikz takes "below of" literally, such a relationship will not turned upside down. If you use coordinates for positioning the nodes, mirroring works.

Comment: To obtain a drawing that is robust w.r.t. mirroring, as rule of thumb you may not use explicit units, no verbal placement options, and no label options of nodes. You have to position everything in relative coordinates. See my first three questions that I asked here ([at the bottom of this page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/110998/gernot?tab=questions)). You are much faster copying the code and editing everything to the mirrored values than reconstructing your graph with methods that are robust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain a free copy of a scope by `\spy`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, arrows.meta,spy}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                prod/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, fill=black!5, black!20},
                ct/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=5pt, ultra thick, minimum width=10mm, fill=black!5, black!20},
                ft/.style={circle, draw, minimum width=8mm, inner sep=1pt, fill=black!5, black!20},
                filter/.style={circle, draw, minimum width=7mm, inner sep=1pt, fill=black!5, black!20},
                mylabel/.style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily},
                >=LaTeX
            ]
        \begin{scope}[spy scope]
            \node[ct, label={[mylabel, black!20]Memory cell}, fill=black!5] (ct) {};
            \node[filter, right=of ct, fill=black!5] (int1) {$f_g$};
            \node[prod, right=of int1, fill=black!5] (x1) {$\times$}; 
            \node[right=of x1] (ht) {$h_t$};
            \node[prod, left=of ct, fill=black!5] (x2) {$\times$}; 
            \node[filter, left=of x2, fill=black!5] (int2) {$f_h$};
            \node[prod, below=5mm of ct, fill=black!5] (x3) {$\times$}; 
            \node[ft, below=5mm of x3, label={[mylabel, black!20]right:Forget gate}, fill=black!5] (ft) {$f_t$};
            \node[ft, above=of x2, label={[mylabel, black!20]left:Input gate}, fill=black!5] (it) {$f_t$};
            \node[ft, above=of x1, label={[mylabel, black!20]left:Output gate}, fill=black!5] (ot) {$f_t$};
            \foreach \i/\j in {int2/x2, x2/ct, ct/int1, int1/x1, x1/ht, it/x2, ct/it, ct/ot, ot/x1, ft/x3}
                \draw[->, black!20] (\i)--(\j);
            \draw[->, black!20] (ct) to[bend right=45] (ft);
            \draw[->, black!20] (ct) to[bend right=30] (x3);
            \draw[->, black!20] (x3) to[bend right=30] (ct);
            \node[fit=(int2) (it) (ot) (ft), draw, inner sep=0pt] (fit) {};
            \draw[<-] (fit.west|-int2) coordinate (aux)--++(180:7mm) node[left]{$x_t$};
            \draw[<-, black!20] ([yshift=1mm]aux)--++(135:7mm);
            \draw[<-, black!20] ([yshift=-1mm]aux)--++(-135:7mm);
            \draw[<-] (fit.north-|it) coordinate (aux)--++(90:7mm) node[above]{$x_t$};
            \draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=1mm]aux)--++(45:7mm);
            \draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=-1mm]aux)--++(135:7mm);
            \draw[<-] (fit.north-|ot) coordinate (aux)--++(90:7mm) node[above]{$x_t$};
            \draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=1mm]aux)--++(45:7mm);
            \draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=-1mm]aux)--++(135:7mm);
            \draw[<-] (fit.south-|ft) coordinate (aux)--++(-90:7mm) node[below]{$x_t$};
            \draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=1mm]aux)--++(-45:7mm);
            \draw[<-, black!20] ([xshift=-1mm]aux)--++(-135:7mm);

            \spy [blue, size=10cm]on(0,0)in node[transform shape,yscale=-1]at(0,10);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the duplicating and mirroring works just as I wanted! Do you think it is still possible to draw arrows between the two different "instances" with this method?

Comment: @StephenJohnson It would be quite hard. However, I suggest that you can draw the arrows before mirroring. (If I understand correctly, all arrows are on the either side.)